# Is there a way I can remove spaces from an unpacked list?

Tags: python

I created a list with `random` and `string` methods, and what is it does it just create 1 uppercase letter and then print 6 lowercase letters.

Now, it is always creating a space between the characters, how can I remove the spaces ?

**Example:**

```
mport random
import string

randomProfile = [random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)] + random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=6)

print(*randomProfile) # unpack the list
```

**Example of output:**

```
W t o v s q j
```

Comment: `print(*randomProfile, sep='')`

Comment: Or `''.join(randomProfile )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we could use

```
"".join(randomProfile)
```

`str.join(iterable)` joins the elements of `iterable` by a given "glue"-string `str`, which is empty in our case.

Comment: But why this is happening, why its creating a space between the chars

Comment: Because `print` adds the space as a separator.